# Swift round up for respondsToSelector() and sizeWithFont()

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am translating the following `Objective-C` code into `Swift`:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    CGSize valueLabelSize = CGSizeZero;

    if ([self.valueLabel.text respondsToSelector:@selector(sizeWithAttributes:)])
    {
        valueLabelSize = [self.valueLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.valueLabel.font}];
    }
    else
    {
        valueLabelSize = [self.valueLabel.text sizeWithFont:self.valueLabel.font];
    }

    CGFloat xOffset = ceil((self.bounds.size.width - valueLabelSize.width) * 0.5);
    self.valueLabel.frame = CGRectMake(xOffset, ceil(self.bounds.size.height * 0.5) - ceil(valueLabelSize.height * 0.5), valueLabelSize.width, valueLabelSize.height);
}
```

This code basically loads dynamically an `UILabel` in the middle of the `UIView` respecting the relative font size and the padding of the view. This is the code I currently have:

```
override func layoutSubviews()
{
    var valueSize = CGSizeZero

    if valueLabel.text != nil {
        if ((self.valueLabel.text! as NSString).respondsToSelector(Selector("sizeWithAttributes:"))){
            valueSize = (self.valueLabel.text! as NSString).sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:self.valueLabel.font])
        }
    }

    let xOffSet = ceil((self.bounds.size.width - valueSize.width) * 0.5)
    valueLabel.frame = CGRectMake(xOffSet, ceil(self.bounds.size.height * 0.5) - ceil(valueSize.height * 0.5), valueSize.width, valueSize.height)
}
```

This is not working correctly cause the label appears in the left-top corner of the view. **I believe there is some round up in swift** for not using the `respondsToSelector()` method but do not know how. I also want to avoid using `sizeWithFont()` cause it's ***deprecated***.

Any help will be very welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally made it work using the `superview` property:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    var valueSize = CGSizeZero
    if let textValue = valueLabel.text {
        valueSize = textValue.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:self.valueLabel.font])
    }
    var unitSize = CGSizeZero
    if let textUnit = unitLabel.text {
        unitSize = textUnit.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:self.unitLabel.font])
    }
    let xOffset = ceil((superview!.bounds.size.width - (valueSize.width + unitSize.width)) * 0.5)
    valueLabel.frame = CGRectMake(xOffset, ceil(superview!.bounds.size.height * 0.5) - ceil(valueSize.height * 0.5), valueSize.width, valueSize.height)
    unitLabel.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(valueLabel.frame), ceil(superview!.bounds.size.height * 0.5) - ceil(unitSize.height * 0.5) + iMinistryValueInformationViewPadding, unitSize.width, unitSize.height)
}
```

Thanks anyway for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `label.sizeToFit()` to set the correct label size to fit your content?

For example:

```
class CustomView : UIView {
    lazy var textLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()

        //  Setup your label's text attributes here.
        //  e.g. font size

        self.addSubview(label)

        return label
    }()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        //  By this point the `text` for the label and all attributes
        //  that could affect the text size need to be set.
        textLabel.sizeToFit()
        textLabel.center = CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2, y: frame.height / 2)
    }
}
```

The result:

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have seen that method but how would the code look like?

Comment: I am sorry I tried this yestarday at home and for my case it didn't work, the label is still in the wrong place :S